# Bash: adding array element different behavior from script vs interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have the following code:

```
numbers=()
a=()
a+=('foo bar baz')
for ((x=0; x<=9; x++));
do
    numbers+=($x)
done

echo $numbers
echo $a
```

When I run this interactively in the shell via copy/pasting it, then I get the output that I want, which is:

```
➜ echo $numbers
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
➜ echo $a
foo bar baz
```

However, when I run it as a script I get:

```
0
foo bar baz
```

Why? And how can I turn it into the behavior with the interactive shell?

Full disclosure: I Googled extensively and couldn't find it. I run zsh and assume it is the same as bash in this case. I'm not very familiar with bash and the interactive shell vs file differences.

**Edit**

After the helpful comments I now found the strange culprit.
I think it has something to do with `chmod +x`.

I created a simpler script:

```
for ((x=0; x<=9; x+=1)) do numbers+=($x); done; echo $numbers;
echo $SHELL
```

This is the output (I'm in a folder called `magic`):

```
chmod +x ./test
➜  magic ./test 
0
/bin/zsh
➜  magic zsh ./test 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
/bin/zsh
```

Could it be that `chmod +x` sets it as a bash executable?

Comment: While I still do not know why there is a different observed behavior, this answer helped me solve my specific problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211395/in-a-loop-over-an-array-add-an-element-to-the-array -- I'm still curious as to why the difference is there.

Comment: I can't replicate your difference in zsh. ZSH seems happy within a shell script or out on the terminal with `for ((x=0; x<=9; x+=1)) do numbers+=($x); done; echo $numbers;` bash doesn't like this one bit though and forces you to print the array with `echo ${numbers[@]}`. Perhaps your terminal is bash but you are executing scripts in zsh?  Try `echo $SHELL` and see what pops up.

Comment: I also tried that loop in `csh`, `ksh`, and `fish`. `csh` and `fish` had syntax errors and `ksh` acted like `bash`, so I assume your user default shell is one of those two.

Comment: Please show the exact script and how you are running it?

Comment: This is the exact script, I'm running it on OS X Yosemite in a `zsh` shell (and naively assumed it acts the same as `bash`). I use `chmod +x` to make my file executable. For more information see my edit.

Comment: The output of zero is similar in bash as you created an array called numbers but then only referred to the first element by using $ only instead of ${numbers[@]}.  When executed, because you have no shebang inside the script it should default to your shell so I have no idea why calling with zsh would then change the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your code in `zsh` in your terminal, where `echo $numbers` outputs the contents of the entire array. In the script, it is run with `sh` (lacking a shebang), so `echo $numbers` is equivalent to `echo ${numbers[0]}`, outputing only the first element. (Your `sh` appears to be a link to `bash`, since the array syntax still works otherwise.)

Your `a` array, however, only *has* one element, the string `foo bar baz`, because you quoted it. To add multiple elements, you would use `a+=(foo bar baz)`, so that the whitespace would be interpreted as separating separate array elements, rather than literal spaces.

The value of `$SHELL` is the name of your default shell, not the name of the shell that is currently running.